# Adaptive 3-columns layout with flexible height of the items without JS?

Tags: html, css

I have a layout for the whole website which is quite standard - header/footer, two side blocks and the main content in the center. Let's put footer/header away, they're not really interesting. What I want to achieve is two things:

1. Make adaptive layout on mobile phones by putting *red* block **between** cyan and green.
2. In the same time keep the layout on desktops flexible. Namely, I don't want to have extra spaces between blue and red blocks (when cyan block has a lot of content), nor I want extra spaces between cyan and green blocks (when blue block has a lot of content)

First I did it with flexbox, but bullet #1 was not possible in Flex. Now I rewrote it to using Grid and faced issues with #2.

**Question** - how do I make grid elements in each column "independent" from each other in terms of height (keeping the deterministic behavior, of course)?

Here is the schematic layout (top - desktop, bottom - mobile):

[image: Layout]

And here is the [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/lega4/pen/BaQXGaX) (click on magenta block to check how does it behave and what's the issue)

```js
var testing = true;

function startTime() {
  if (testing) {

    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br><br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>";

    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "Short content (logs block should start just after me)";
  } else {

    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>LongLongContent<br>";
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "Short content (photos block should start just after me)";
  }
  testing = !testing;
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 210px 1fr 200px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" 
                       "info content sidebar"
                       "photos logs sidebar"
                       "footer footer footer";
}

.grid-container>* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.info {
  grid-area: info;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.photos {
  grid-area: photos;
  background-color: red;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: magenta;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.logs {
  grid-area: logs;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header class="grid-container">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <div class="info" id="info">Info<br>Info<br>Info<br>Info<br>Info<br>Info<br><br>Info<br></div>
  <div class="photos">Photos<br>Photos<br>Photos<br>Photos<br>Photos<br></div>
  <div class="content" id="content">content<br>asdasd<br><br><br>[I'm some random empty space =(]</div>
  <div class="logs">logs</div>
  <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar" onclick="startTime()">Click me to toggle between different sizes of content</div>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code shows the implementation of the structure of a variable height grid. Note that the corresponding columns must be the same height.

**Using `grid-template-areas:` you can implement your desired structure.**

Pay attention to how to implement the `grid-container` class

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  grid-template-areas: 
            "one two three"
            "one four three"
            "five six three"
}
```

With `grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;` 3 columns are defined.

Then with

```
 grid-template-areas:
                 "one two three"
                 "one four three"
                 "five six three"
```

3 rows are defined by 3 columns.

> I used the following code for the responsive mode

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  grid-template-areas: 
            "two"
            "four"
            "five"
            "six"
  }
}
```

***Full code:***

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25%;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  grid-template-areas: "one two three" "one four three" "five six three"
}

#one {
  grid-area: one;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#two {
  grid-area: two;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#three {
  grid-area: three;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #365263;
}

#four {
  grid-area: four;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#five {
  grid-area: five;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#six {
  grid-area: six;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.grid-container>div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    grid-template-areas: "two" "four" "five" "six"
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>The grid-column Property</h1>



<div class="grid-container">
  <div id="one">2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>2<br>1</div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three">3</div>
  <div id="four">4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br>4<br></div>
  <div id="five">5</div>
  <div id="six">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't really help me because you put multiple divs inside one column container. This will not work for bullet #1. It also looks completely different from my suggested layout.

Comment: I changed the code to suit your needs. You can check it out.

Comment: No? This doesn't work completely, columns are not flexible  and even worse than in my code in the question (bullet #2) https://codepen.io/lega4/pen/eYBqozP. Please refer to my initial codepen example and see the issue.

Comment: I changed the height to auto. The corresponding columns receive the same height.

Comment: ...and you got the very same example as in my question with empty spaces instead of dynamic height.... Exactly what I was questioning about... Did you actually read and understand my question, clicked on my initial codepen before answering?

Comment: As I understand it, the usual structure for implementing such a case is to use the 3 columns that I entered in the first example, but if you want to implement it according to the grid structure, I can help you so far.